# Installing Grunt on OS X

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

Here's what I've done so far:

```
brew install nodejs npm
npm install -g grunt
```

I've also set up my path to include the proper directories. When I run `echo $PATH` I get:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/lib/node:/usr/local/lib/node_modules:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/landonschropp/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/lib/node:/usr/local/lib/node_modules:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

The installation succeeds without any problems. However, if I try to run `grunt` I get this error:

```
zsh: permission denied: grunt
```

Did I miss a step?

Comment: You may need to `sudo npm install -g grunt`.

Comment: Hmm, I still end up with the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo grunt` to see if it may be a permissions issue?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try installing the command line interface:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Comment: You're welcome. Have fun with Grunt, i'm using it since last week and it is great!

Answer (score 5):

`sudo npm install -g grunt-cli` and then type your password.

Comment: OMG I read ~dozen posts before I realized this was the issue.  Why was there no err msg?

Comment: AFAIK you shouldn't need to `sudo` install anything for an OS X development environment, and doing so could cause unexpected problems.

Comment: +1 @eirikir. Reference: [Homebrew FAQ: Why does Homebrew say sudo is bad?](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad-)

Comment: @itorres `npm` != `brew`

Comment: @Armand, in this question `npm` has been installed through homebrew, hence `sudo` should be avoided. If a homebrew user needs to use sudo to alter /usr/local it means the install is botched.